# 301 Redirect entire virtual host without including URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

So I have a site setup for http://weddings.gigmasters.com like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName weddings.gigmasters.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.gigmasters.com/events/wedding
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, as you can see, when you go to http://weddings.gigmasters.com, it properly redirects. However, when I go to something like http://weddings.gigmasters.com/a-url-goes-here, it goes to http://www.gigmasters.com/events/weddinga-url-goes-here, which is absolutely not what I want. Is there a way using apache redirect to redirect without the URL appended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out Apache has `RedirectMatch`, which can be used like this:

`RedirectMatch 301 (.+)  http://www.gigmasters.com/events/wedding`

...to basically capture any URL and quash it, and then just redirect to the proper URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Redirectmatch` instead with regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!events/wedding$).*$ /events/wedding
```